# Android ViewPager does not work as expected

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I tried to make an infinite ViewPager which contains three views:

```
    int lastPos;

    pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int pos, float v, int i2) {
            Log.d("page", "scoll:" + pos);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int pos) {
            Log.d("page", "selected:" + pos);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            Log.d("page", "state:" + state);
            if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
                lastPos = getCurrentItem();
            }
            if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                Log.d("page", "idle");
                int npos = getCurrentItem();
                if (npos != lastPos) {
                    setCurrentItem(1, false);
                    //resetPageContent(npos - lastPos);  //npos - lastPos  ==> Negative means left, positive means right.
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

As shown, I will  reset the current item to 1 (to make the pager can swip), then I will change the page content accordingly.

However I have some questions now:

1) The OnPageChangeListener:

I add some log to make sure what happened during the phase of the `OnPageChangeListener`, this is the result:

```
page﹕ scoll:1
page﹕ state:1
page﹕ scoll:1
page﹕ scoll:1
page﹕ scoll:1
page﹕ scoll:1
page﹕ state:2
page﹕ selected:2
page﹕ scoll:1
page﹕ scoll:1
page﹕ scoll:1
page﹕ scoll:1
page﹕ scoll:1
page﹕ scoll:1
page﹕ scoll:2
page﹕ state:0
page﹕ idle
page﹕ selected:1
page﹕ scoll:1
```

I can not understand that the `onPageScrolled` will be called event after the page scroll state have became to  `IDLE`.

And the `onPageSelected` are called twice.

Why?

2 The infinite does not work as expected.

Once I scroll the `ViewPager` normally, it works, however once I scroll it much quickly, the `ViewPager` will come to an end at some time.

I am not sure what's the problem. I hope someone can give me some help.

---

update: the whole viewpager codes:

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {
    private MyPagerAdapter myPagerAdapter;
    private int lastPos = 1;

    private int globalIndex = 1;

    private SinglePageView[] mPages = new SinglePageView[3];

    public CustomViewPager(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }


    public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        myPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
        setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int pos, float v, int i2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int pos) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    int npos = getCurrentItem();
                    if (npos != lastPos) {
                        resetPageContent(npos - lastPos);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        if (changed) {
            int w = r - l, h = b - t;

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                mPages[i] = new SinglePageView(getContext());
                mPages[i].setMinimumWidth(w);
                mPages[i].setMinimumHeight(h);
            }
            setAdapter(myPagerAdapter);
            resetPageContent(0);
        }
    }

    private void resetPageContent(int dir) {

        if (dir > 0) {
            globalIndex++;
        } else if (dir < 0)
            globalIndex--;

        mPages[1].setContent(String.valueOf(globalIndex));

        globalIndex--;
        mPages[0].setContent(String.valueOf(globalIndex));
        globalIndex++;

        globalIndex++;
        mPages[2].setContent(String.valueOf(globalIndex));
        globalIndex--;


        setCurrentItem(1, false);
        globalIndex++;
    }


    class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        private MyPagerAdapter() {
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mPages.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            SinglePageView spv = mPages[position];
            container.addView(spv, 0);
            return spv;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
            return view == (View) o;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((View) object);
        }
    }

    class SinglePageView extends View {
        private String mContent = "Unassigned";
        private Paint mPaint;

        public SinglePageView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            mPaint = new Paint();
            mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            canvas.save();
            canvas.drawText(mContent, 100, 100, mPaint);
            canvas.restore();
        }

        public void setContent(String content) {
            mContent = content;
        }
    }
}
```

Although the content are not calculated correctly at the moment, but it is infinite until if you swipe quickly,demo:http://imgbin.org/images/18754.gif

Comment: As i understood your viewpager has just 3 views so can you explain what you mean by infinite?

Comment: There are only three views, but I will keep resetting the current item to 1, and updating the content of the views.

Comment: and also what is your adapter? FragmentStatePagerAdapter or FragmantPagerAdapter.

Comment: i downloaded your code and create new prj in eclipse after that i changed the background of 3 views so page[0] is red page[1] is green and page[2] is blue. i am scrolling it  and its working, i am scrolling it fast and its working, i do not understand what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: Maybe not fast enough.

Comment: @mmlooloo: I upload a demo, check the update.

Comment: No idea man, because i test it on genymotion and galaxy s3 and it works!!

Answer (score 0):

if you use ViewPager to contain Fragment ,you can use mViewPage.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter());
and you don't need to implement listener.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Fragment  you could do like this:

First:
In your layout xml :

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

Second：

```
public static class MyFragment extends Fragment {


    public static Fragment getInstanceFragment(int sectionNumber) {     
        return getFragment(sectionNumber);

    }


    private static Fragment getFragment(int sectionNumber) {


        switch (sectionNumber) {

        case 0:
             return  Fragment.instantiate(mContext,
                    FirstFragment.class.getName());

        case 1:
            return  Fragment.instantiate(mContext,SecondFragment.class.getName());
        case 1:
            return  Fragment.instantiate(mContext,ThirdFragment.class.getName());


        default :   
            return  Fragment.instantiate(mContext,FirstFragment.class.getName());

        }


    }

}
```

Third:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        return MyFragment.getInstanceFragment(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return "First Fragment";
        case 1:
            return "Second Fragment";

        case 2:
            return "Second Fragment";
        default:
              return "First Fragment";

        }

    }


}
```

Then :

```
 ViewPager mViewPage = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

 SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

 mViewPage.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);;
```

If you want implement ViewPaper's Listener:

```
mViewPage.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {


        }


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

For infine ViewPager I have written my own code like [this](https://github.com/UdaySravanK/USK_Public_Rep/tree/master/APIs/Android/USKInfiniteViewPager)